# Why is WordPress redirecting from http to https on a local environment?

Tags: redirect, ssl, https, http, local-installation

I recently set up a live WordPress site on my local environment through Duplicator. I can access the `wp-admin` but I cannot access the main site as wp redirects the site from `http` to `https` automatically. I checked the `.htaccess`, but no luck. I checked the `wp_options` table and it has an entry of the site with `http` not `https`. Can you tell what seems to be the problem and what files should I be looking at? Thanks.

Edit:
I cleaned the browser cache (even ran it on incognito), still no luck.

Comment: Which browser, which version, and how exactly is the local URL you access the site with?

Comment: Also: Did you try different browsers?

Comment: You can go to the db and update the site in the options table to first remove https, then investigate options to simulate a cert locally, some simple steps to follow here, but only on your local machine: https://really-simple-ssl.com/knowledge-base/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-mamp/

Comment: I tried all the above; nothing workden. In my case some plugin was probably causing this. Only when i disabled the complete Plugin folder (by renaming it to 0_Plugins) the site came up. Now I have to manually figure out which of the plugins was causing this. Thanks for the other tips.

Answer (score 7):

Well, at my situation... I downloaded the company website from production to localhost because I was needed to prepare a development environment for some developers. The production is using https:// and at localhost http://, and when I ran it the first time on localhost, it always redirected me to the https://.

And, I have managed to made this working on my localhost simply by adding the following lines in the wp-config.php (my wp version was 4.9.8):

```
define('FORCE_SSL', false);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you don't have installed and activated a plugin that forces a redirection to HTTPS, for example, the [Really Simple SSL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/). If you have one, deactivate it on the localhost by renaming the plugin folder name, e.g. rename it from `"really-simple-ssl"` to `"really-simple-ssl_deactivated"`. Now you should be able to access your `wp-admin` URL.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can access /wp-admin/, the solution is pretty simple - clean your browser cache or try to open your website in incognito tab.

Comment: Sorry. I should've stated that I tried the things you mentioned, still not working out.

Comment: Did you make all database replacements?

Comment: for that I thought Duplicator takes care of though I checked the wp_options table if registered url is on https, but no it's on http. any other table i should be checking into?

Comment: Of course, I recommend yo use this tool to generate all database queries for your phpMyAdmin https://rudrastyh.com/tools/sql-queries-generator

Answer (score 0):

You should comment out these lines in `.htaccess` file

```
#RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
#RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with `wp cli`.

1. Install `wp-cli` using the instruction [here](https://wp-cli.org#installing)
2. run `wp plugin deactivate really-simple-ssl` from terminal.

You can also add autocomplete to your bash terminal so you can easily see suggestion of plugins you have installed.